# How do I initialize app with external JSON?

Tags: vue.js

I need to initialize my app with external json data. The problem I'm getting is that I can't force the app to wait loading children components for after the data arrives.

For example, let's use this as an example (not external loading here, I'm using `setTimeout` to make a point of waiting for data to arrive).

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  beforeCreate() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myConfig = 'loaded'; // I realize I'm not using $data here, but nevermind
    }, 1000)
  },
});
```

And in my child component

```
created() {
  console.log(this.$root.myConfig);
},
```

The problem is that `created` from the child is called before the beforeCreate finishes.

Data won't change from initial state. Thus, I don't need the reactivity of VueX.

As I'm using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/), an option maybe is to create a loading component as the default route, which should load the data, and then on arrival switch to the correct initial state.

Also, by looking at [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components), maybe it's what I should use, but I get the feeling that it's a little more complicated than what I need.

Is there a best practice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple boolean to hide the components while the data is loading with `v-if`. Set a variable named `loading` to `true` and change it to `false` when you're done loading. Then use `v-if="!loading"` on your component. You might want a nice loading text or spinner there for the user.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: true,
      myConfig: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loading = false
      this.myConfig = 'loaded'
    }, 2000)
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="loading">loading...</p>
  <p v-else>{{ myConfig }}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.4/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this directs you:

```js
console.log('wait for 1 second')

new Vue({
  template: '#app',
  created () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myConfig = 'loaded'
      this.$mount('#app')
    }, 1000)
  },
});
```

```html
<template id="app">
  <p>{{ myConfig }}</p>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.4/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

For more advanced 'preinitialization' look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157499/initialization-logic-before-preparing-vue-js-frontend/) example.